# Receive all accounts mails with one admin account in java

Tags: java, email

Is there any way that can be used with java to receive all emails of all emails belonging to a domain `[any mail account]@domain.com` without logging in to each mail account, but by using one admin account to login.
I don't know if this is possible with **Apache James**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) in java to access the REST API provided by Apache James

for Apache James look at 
https://james.apache.org/server/manage-webadmin.html

more specifically the part on "[Listing mails contained in a mail repository](https://james.apache.org/server/manage-webadmin.html#Listing_mails_contained_in_a_mail_repository)" .

> ```
> curl -XGET http://ip:port/mailRepositories/encodedPathOfTheRepository/mails
> ```
>
> Resource name encodedPathOfTheRepository should be the resource path
>   of an existing mail repository. Example:
>
> ```
> curl -XGET http://ip:port/mailRepositories/var%2Fmail%2Ferror%2F/mails The answer
> ```
>
> will contains all mailKey contained in that repository.
>
> ```
> [
>     "mail-key-1",
>     "mail-key-2",
>     "mail-key-3" ]
> ```
>
> Note that this can be used to read mail details.

After listing, you can get then [read or download all the mail details](https://james.apache.org/server/manage-webadmin.html#Reading_a_mail_details)

> ```
> curl -XGET http://ip:port/mailRepositories/encodedPathOfTheRepository/mails/mailKey
> ```
>
> Resource name encodedPathOfTheRepository should be the resource path
>   of an existing mail repository. Resource name mailKey should be the
>   key of a mail stored in that repository. Example:
>
> ```
> curl -XGET http://ip:port/mailRepositories/var%2Fmail%2Ferror%2F/mails/mail-key-1
> ```
>
> If the Accept header in the request is “application/json”, then the
>   response looks like:
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "mail-key-1",
>     "sender": "sender@domain.com",
>     "recipients": ["recipient1@domain.com", "recipient2@domain.com"],
>     "state": "address-error",
>     "error": "A small message explaining what happened to that mail...",
>     "remoteHost": "111.222.333.444",
>     "remoteAddr": "127.0.0.1",
>     "lastUpdated": null
> }
> ```
>
> If the Accept header in the request is “message/rfc822”, then the
>   response will be the eml file itself.
>
> Additional query parameter additionalFields add the existing
>   informations to the response for the supported values: - attributes -
>   headers - textBody - htmlBody - messageSize - perRecipientsHeaders
>
> ```
> curl -XGET http://ip:port/mailRepositories/file%3A%2F%2Fvar%2Fmail%2Ferror%2F/mails/mail-key-1?
> ```
>
> additionalFields=attributes,headers,textBody,htmlBody,messageSize,perRecipientsHeaders Give the following kind of response:
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "mail-key-1",
>     "sender": "sender@domain.com",
>     "recipients": ["recipient1@domain.com", "recipient2@domain.com"],
>     "state": "address-error",
>     "error": "A small message explaining what happened to that mail...",
>     "remoteHost": "111.222.333.444",
>     "remoteAddr": "127.0.0.1",
>     "lastUpdated": null,
>     "attributes": {
>       "name2": "value2",
>       "name1": "value1"
>     },
>     "perRecipientsHeaders": {
>       "third@party": {
>         "headerName1": [
>           "value1",
>           "value2"
>         ],
>         "headerName2": [
>           "value3",
>           "value4"
>         ]
>       }
>     },
>     "headers": {
>       "headerName4": [
>         "value6",
>         "value7"
>       ],
>       "headerName3": [
>         "value5",
>         "value8"
>       ]
>     },
>     "textBody": "My body!!",
>     "htmlBody": "My <em>body</em>!!",
>     "messageSize": 42424242
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can you Java Mail API for this, then you can check the domaine using java code.